How to format a Tic Tac Toe Board (Python)
Essentially, I am trying to format a tic tac toe board, so it prints in a 3 by 3 pattern with grid lines.
First, I tried hardcoding a grid but then it wasn't editable. Now I made a list of lists, and I am trying to iterate through each element, and for each element print lines adjacent to it. however, when I do this, I run into "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str", and now I am unsure what to do.
relevant code:
class Tictactoe:

    def __init__(self, playerone, playertwo,):
        self.playerone = playerone
        self.playertwo = playertwo
        
        

    def newBoard(self):
        # creates new board
        return [[None, None, None],
                 [None, None, None],
                 [None, None, None]
                 ]
        
        
        
        


    def renderBoard(self):
        #todo: prints current state of board
        board = self.newBoard()
        for i in board:
            print("|" + i + "|")



    def getMove(self):
        #todo: get inputfor current player's move
        pass

    def makeMove(self):
        #todo: code the current player's move
        pass

    def getWinner(self):
        #todo write win conditions
        '''if player one marks 3 in a row, player one wins, end game
        if player two marks 3 in a row, player 2 wins, end game
        '''
        pass

    def resetButton(self):
        #todo: create a reset button that clears the board.
        pass

    def runGame(self):
        #todo: write code that starts the game.
        pass

    def isBoardFull(self):
        #todo: write code that checks if board is full
        pass


def main():
    test = Tictactoe("playerone", "playertwo")
    test.renderBoard()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


board is a list of lists.  for i in board: make i a list as it iterates, e.g. [None, None, None].  Use print to debug variables and add them before the line that fails to see what is going wrong or learn to use a source debugger.

print(f"|{i}|")

Solution
def newBoard(self):
    # creates new board
    return [['x', 'o', ' '], # add markers to board
            [' ', ' ', ' '],
            [' ', ' ', ' ']]

def renderBoard(self):
    #todo: prints current state of board
    board = self.newBoard()
     
    print(f" {board[0][0]} | {board[0][1]} |  {board[0][2]} ")
    print("---+---+---")
    print(f" {board[1][0]} | {board[1][1]} |  {board[1][2]} ")
    print("---+---+---")
    print(f" {board[2][0]} | {board[2][1]} |  {board[2][2]} ")

The problem that you were running into was that you were trying to print out a row of the board but the + operator doesn't know how to handle those types. So to keep things simple, I've hard coded the board but I'm using f"{}" so that I can print out the current state of the board. Now, you can update the board by passing in the index to the game board.

board = ["-","-","-",
     "-","-","-",
     "-","-","-"]
winner = None
gameRunning = True
 currentPlayer = "x"
def printboard(board):
    print(board[0] + "|" + board[1] +"|" + board[2])
    print(board[3] + "|" + board[4] + "|" + board[5])
    print(board[6] + "|" + board[7] + "|" + board[8])
   def player(board):
   num = int(input("enter number between 1-9"))
   if num>=1 and num<=9 and board[num-1]=="-":
    board[num-1]=currentPlayer
    def row(board):
    global winner
    if board[0]== board[1]==board[2] and board[0]!="-":
       winner = board[0]
        return True
    elif board[3]==board[4]==board[5] and board[3]!="":
         winner = board[3]
        return True
     elif board[6]==board[7]==board[8] and board[6]!="-"":
    winner=  board[6]
    return True
def column(board):
    global winner
    if board[0]==board[3]==board[6] and board[0]!="-":
        winner= board[0]
        return True
    elif board[1]==board[4]==board[7] and board[1]!="-":
        winner = board[1]
    return True
elif board[2]==board[5]==board[8] and board[2]!="-":
    winner =  board[2]
        return True
def slant(board):
    global winner
    if board[0]==board[4]==board[8] and board[0]!="-":
        winner = board[0]
        return True
    elif board[2]==board[4]==board[6] and board[2]!="-":
        winner = board[2]
        return True
def checktie(board):
    global gameRunning
    if "-" not in board:
        printboard(board)
        print("it is a tie")
        return False
def checkwin():
    if row(board) or column(board)or slant(board):
        print(f"the winner is {winner}")
def switchPlayer():
    global currentPlayer
    if currentPlayer=="x":
        currentPlayer="o"
    else:
        currentPlayer=="x"

while gameRunning:
   printboard(board)
   player(board)
   switchPlayer()
   checktie(board)
   checkwin()


Please provide an explanation of how this code answers the question.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
